# Custom Django All-auth signup form not sending confirmation email after signup

Tags: django, django-allauth

So I have a custom user that extends the base user.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    is_renter = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is my custom user creation form - makes the user a renter if they use this form.

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'username')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_renter = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

```
class RenterSignupPageView(generic.CreateView):
    model = CustomUser
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'account/renter_signup.html'
```

This is my view right now, but it doesn't send the confirmation email as if I used the default signupform. The email only get sent if I attempt to login with the account...

Is this the proper way to implement different user types? Should I be using SignUpForm? if so, can that allow different user types, views, and urls?

Comment: Please show the code where you are sending an email

Comment: I don't have one...I'm assuming inheriting the AbstractUser triggers the same functionalities, because if I were to try and login - it then triggers the authentication email via the all-auth source code.